# FB PHP SDK + Design: How to build login system with facebook

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, facebook-login

I've read almost everything from the docs but it's still not clear for me how to work with the access tokens of facebook to build my own login system.

Let me try to explain what I've understood.

1. I create a `facebookRedirectLoginHelper`.
2. Then I get a FacebookSession object from the helper with `getSessionFromRedirect`
3. Then I can get a token with `getToken` which I can save in a session and cookie.

How should I implement it with my database?

My thoughts were I could have a user table which holds also the `oauth_id` (facebook id of the user) and `fb_token`. But for example how long is the token valid? **How can I check if the token is still valid?**

Is it **save** enough (and **correct** from the idea) to build the "logged" system in that way that as long the `access_token cookie` and `session` are set, the user is valid logged in?

Best regards,
Michael

**Edit**: Another question: Can I use the access token to exactly identify each user? Is it 'almost' unique?

**Edit2**: And why shoould i use the `getLogoutUrl` link which also logs me out of facebook with my private account instead just deleting my cookie and session?

Answer (score 1):

I am here by providing you a link please go through that. there is a zip file containing all required files with doc (readme).

Few Days back i was suffering with same problem so i created one module of OAuth so that anyone can use that in any php framework or core php too.

Please read the readme and let me know for any help if you need. it will be great to help you

[Social Login.zip](http://zamocha.com/downloads/social.zip)

Comment: Thanks for the zip. It really helps me but I still need a little more time to dig in deeper. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for commenting late but i am here to help you. Please tell me

Comment: hey do you still have that social.zip folder. if yes can you upload it on a server so that i can download it. I have lost it